# CS203 RF Reader - C# Application

Tags: c#, rfid

I am working on a project with CS203 RF Reader. I want to know how the Callback API is working and need to customize the Demo App to our project requirements.

All we work in C#

If anyone of you can help me understanding the Callback API of CS203 reader that will be real great.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there isn't much documentation for the cs203, and the only real place you can find anything is the user manual. So if you want an answer to a specific problem you should post it here as a question, this way people with experience with this device might be able to help you with that problem.

Comment: Thanks friend. I will come back with my specific question.